# Why does PowerShell give "Access Denied" for Get-Content on a directory?

Tags: powershell

By accident, I recently tried running `Get-Content` on a directory. I'd initially thought it was a file because it was named very similarly to a common file I'd expected to be in the location. So I was further confused when I was given an "Access Denied" error in a location where I should have full control.

Of course, I eventually realized my mistake. Once I actually pointed `Get-Content` at some files in the same area, or in subfolders of that path, it worked fine. But the error still strikes me as odd. At the very least, I figure it would be more user-friendly and sensible to present an error that actually says (albeit more politely) "That's not a file you're trying to look at, genius!".

Why does "Access Denied" make sense in this context?

Comment: It not PowerShell returns "Access Denied", but Windows do so. Try `notepad SomeDirectory` and you will get same error.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the process - be it PowerShell, Notepad, etc tries to open the directory as if it were a file.

Sine "File Permissions" can't be read for a file (I know NTFS permissions can be set and look the same, but under the hood they aren't) - it generates an "Access Denied" message which is passed to whatever program you tried to use.